# How to implement jQuery alert message in Angular 2?

Tags: html, angular

I have a form and on click of the "send message" button I need to show a Alert message which uses jQuery but for this alert message to become visible I have to double click instead I want it to be fired in one click only.

Here is my HTML code for alert message:--

```
<button>View Alert</button>
<div class="alert-container">
  <i class="icon fa fa-comments"></i>
  <p class="alert-message">New message from me</p>
  <div class="extra">View this message</div>
</div>
```

Here is the jQuery for alert message:--

```
$('button').click(function(){
  $('.alert-container').addClass('active');

  setTimeout(function(){
    $('.alert-container').removeClass('active');
  }, 3000);
});
```

Comment: I have to double click for the alert message to become visible which instead should be visible on a single click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to add a click event to the element you are clicking.

http://learnangular2.com/events/

```
<button (click)="clicked()">Click</button>
```

Then in your component's code you defined the clicked() function and put the code you want to run onclick in there.

Comment: I have done as you said but still I have to double click to fire the alert message though the function is being called.

Comment: You will also prob need to add a @ViewChild annotation to get a handle on the element you want to play with. To do this you will need to add ... <div #alertContainer class="alert-container"> and then add the ViewChild code to the component class - then in your code you will be able to do .. viewChildElement.addClass('active'); .. that should fix it

Comment: The view child code "viewChildElement.addClass('active')" will be inside my jquerry code?

Comment: no it will be inside your clicked() function. You will have to declare the @ViewChild annotation first inside your component class. You may need to do $(viewChildElement).addClass('active')

Comment: You could you please specify how to add the @View child annotation in a code form that would be very helpful

Comment: Here I added it like this in my ckick function:--                                                                     alert_messagesss(){
   $('viewChildElement').addClass('active');
    $('button').click(function(){
  $('.alert-container').addClass('active');
  setTimeout(function(){
    $('.alert-container').removeClass('active');
  }, 3000);
});
}

Comment: I removed this additional  " $('button').click(function(){} " and it worked fine, as this was already inside click function.